# SqlDataSource parameter from codebehind

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, checkboxlist

i am using sql datasource and a checkboxlist to filter a datalistview.
i want to make a parameter for sqldatasource from code behind and use SQL IN to filter datalistview rows.
when i check 1 checkbox in checkboxlist everything work great...
but when i check more than 1 checkbox datalist view takes no data.
this is my onselecting code for sql datasource:

```
protected void DS_subgroupID_changed_Selecting(object sender,SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    List<String> selected = new List<String>();
    foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxList_subgroup.Items)
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            selected.Add(item.Value);
        }

    String commaselect = String.Join(",", selected.ToArray());
    e.Command.Parameters["@product_subgroup"].Value = commaselect;


}
```

and here is my sqldatasource control:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS_subgroupID_changed" runat="server"
   ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:nimrokhDBConnectionString %>" 
   SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [tbl_product] WHERE (([product_group] = @product_group) AND ([product_subgroup] IN (@product_subgroup)))"
   OnSelecting="DS_subgroupID_changed_Selecting">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="radio_list_group" Name="product_group" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="product_subgroup" />
        </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

i have 1 table subgroup that contains subgroupID as int and subgroupname,
and i have a table product that contan subgroup to store subgroup ID but this is in nvarchar. i wonder if this cause the problem. because my checkboxlist value is set to subgroupID form subgroup table.

i appretiate any help.
thank you guys.

Comment: Probably the problem is the SQL IN.   You need to use a split function on your comma separated string and join to the results.

Comment: but i have read this here:http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012010-1.aspx can you give me a link that describe that manner?

Comment: Yes, this source points you to the correct direction. The problem is you are using `IN` keyword in conjunction with a parameter, which, as the above source explains, does not work.

Comment: Here's an example:  http://www.itdeveloperzone.com/2013/03/using-variable-in-in-clause-in-sql.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterize a SQL IN clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-a-sql-in-clause)

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos above source describe that u can use IN keyword with a parameter but in a particular way. my code works fine when i click only 1 checkbox, and also 1 checkbox goes to sql server with parameter.

Comment: In a *particular* way, yes. This is **not** the way you are using it. You have to use some sort of `dbo.Split` UDF, as the article clearly states.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos please read this section of the article:Programmatically Converting a CheckBoxList's Selected Items Into a Comma-Delimited String....  i have used exactly that aproach ...

Comment: Yes, but you *also* have to change the query used by `SelectCommand` to sth like `AND [product_subgroup] IN (SELECT Value FROM dbo.Split(@product_subgroup,','))` as the article states. You haven't done this part.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos ... oops that was stupid ... thank you man ... i will do it. :D